# Java split collection into smaller parts of same size for a general base type

Tags: java, collections

I want to split collection into smaller partitions. I created a following method for this purpose:

```
/**
 * Splits collection into smaller collections of given size
 * @param c input collection
 * @param partitionSize partition maximum size
 * @return collection of collections
 */
private static Collection<Collection<MyClass>> splitCollection(Collection<MyClass> c, int partitionSize) {
  List<Collection<MyClass>> result = new ArrayList<>();
  List<MyClass> partition = new ArrayList<>();
  for (MyClass o : c) {
    if (partition.size() == partitionSize) {
      result.add(partition);
      partition = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    partition.add(o);
  }
  if (!partition.isEmpty()) {
    result.add(partition);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Now I want to create a general (base type independent) function in order to be able to call something like this:

```
 List<Collection<MyClass>> result = splitCollection(myClassList, 500, MyClass.class);
 List<Collection<MyClass2>> result = splitCollection(myClass2List, 500, MyClass2.class);
```

But how can I achieve this if I don't want to use polymorphism (replace my types with Object)?

Comment: Java made a [stab at generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is use [`Generics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html):

```
private static <T> Collection<Collection<T>> splitCollection(Collection<T> c, int partitionSize) {
    List<Collection<T>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    List<T> partition = new ArrayList<>();
    for (T o : c) {
        if (partition.size() == partitionSize) {
            result.add(partition);
            partition = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        partition.add(o);
    }
    if (!partition.isEmpty()) {
        result.add(partition);
    }
    return result;
}
```

and then you can call it as:

```
Collection<Collection<Integer>> lsts = splitCollection(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4), 2);
Collection<Collection<String>> lsts = splitCollection(Arrays.asList("1","2","3","4"), 2);
```